# Making interface implementations asynchronous

Tags: c#, async-await

I am implementing `System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler` on one of my classes and in the body of my implementation of void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)`I am calling a method using the`async...await` syntax. E.g.

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    if (eventArgument.Equals("deq1"))
    {
        Result result = await SaveDataAsync();
        OnSaved();
    }
}
```

However, it produces the error:

> CS4033 - The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method

[image: CS4033 - The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method]

The question: [Making interface implementations async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458566/making-interface-implementations-async) describes an almost identical problem to mine, with the key difference being that the interface implemented by the OP was under his control, and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459145/909882) was to change `void DoSomething()` on the interface to `Task DoSomething()`. However, I cannot change the `IPostBackEventHandler` as it is part of the .NET Framework.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in a safe way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `async` modifier even if it is not defined in the interface.
**Just take into account that `RaisePostBackEvent` must return void, so it will work as a ["fire and forget"](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) call.** If that is not a problem just add the `async` modifier to the signature.

```
public async void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    if (eventArgument.Equals("deq1"))
    {
        Result result = await SaveDataAsync();
        OnSaved();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if an exception occurs during the save process? How could I handle it?

Comment: You want to handle it in the same method? Just put a try catch. You can use await inside of the try.

Comment: Calling OnSaved() is not a good idea. See Stephen Cleary answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers) SO question and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) MSDN page.

Comment: Unfortunately this is legacy code that requires the `RaisePostBackEvent` to be async due to a method deep down being async (call to put a command on a message bus using MassTransit 3). `OnSaved()` is a virtual method. As this code is part of a web control, I've modified `RaisePostBackEvent` to `Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => RaisePostBackEventAsync(eventArgument)));` and  put the original code into a new method called `RaisePostBackEventAsync(string eventArgument)`

Answer (score 1):

If your method implementation is NOT async, then you cannot "await" inside it.
You can make your method implementation async void even if the interface you're implementing doesn't have async.
You cannot make your method implementation async Task, as that changes the return value which is bad.

The outcome of making your method implementation async void is that the caller will not wait for the method to complete before returning.
try:

```
public async void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    if (eventArgument.Equals("deq1"))
    {
        Result result = await SaveDataAsync();
        OnSaved();
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if an exception occurs during the save process? How could I handle it?

Comment: You can put a try catch around it.